# Vuetify custom filter

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hello I need a custom filter for my table but I don't know how to do it.

I have currently the following code which works kinda:

```
    customFilter(value, search) {
          return (
            value != null &&
            search != null &&
            typeof value === "string" &&
            value.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1
          );
    }
```

but I need to go through an array with one object, too: You can see my data structure here:

```
      invoiceID: "",
      client: [
        {
          _id: "",
          salutation: "",
          companyname: "",
          firstname: "",
          lastname: "",
          street: "",
          housenumber: "",
          zipCode: "",
          place: "",
        },
      ],
      buildingProject: "",
      place: "",
      servicetext: "",
      paid: "",
      transferred: 0,
```

I can search for anything except in client. The client array will always be one size big. The function needs to return a boolean.

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble understanding what you want. Do you want to `include` the client to be searchable too, or do you want to exclude the `client` on your search?

Comment: I want it to be included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I assume that you have a `v-textfield` that is binded to some variable (probably named `search`) used for filtering the table.

Here's my solution:

So basically, the `custom-filter` can return a third param (`item` in this example) which return the whole object that has the `client` property on it. We can then search if one of its properties has matched our search string.

```html
<v-text-field v-model="search" placeholder="Type something to search"></v-text-field>
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="invoices"
  :search="search"
  :custom-filter="customFilter"
></v-data-table>
```

```js
customFilter(value, search, item) {
  // find the search string if it exist in client
  const client = item.client[0];
  const clientKeys = Object.keys(client);
  const hasClientMatch = clientKeys.some(
    key =>
      client[key]
        .toString()
        .toLocaleLowerCase()
        .indexOf(search) !== -1
  );

  return (
    value != null &&
    search != null &&
    typeof value === "string" &&

    // Return the item if it matched somewhere on client, 
    // OR if it matched certain values displayed on the table.
    (hasClientMatch ||        
      value
        .toString()
        .toLocaleLowerCase()
        .indexOf(search) !== -1)
  );
}
```

[Here is a sample demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-river-36t4h?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:2462-3075).

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted.